# Altbeacon Library - didEnterRegion function is not triggered on Background and Foregorund scanning

Tags: android, background, monitoring, scanning, altbeacon

My purpose is when application is closed, application must send notification to user. I used Altbeacon background library for this.

Reference: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/BeaconReferenceApplication.java

Although application sends log that beacons detected,didEnterRegion function is not triggered by BootstrapNotifier. I couldn't understand this case.

My log:

```
 02-25 21:15:39.906 3183-3203/com.beacon.beacondetection.beacondetection D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=E1:B9:E3:76:91:50 RSSI=-50

 02-25 21:15:39.916 3183-3204/com.beacon.beacondetection.beacondetection D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=CC:E0:4C:60:F8:C8 RSSI=-87
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplicationName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

BeaconDetection:

class BeaconDetection extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {

```
private static final String TAG = "BeaconDetection";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
private MainActivity monitoringActivity = null;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(3000l);

    Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
}


@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
    if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
    } else {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
        } else {

            Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification.");
            sendNotification();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    if (monitoringActivity != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    if (monitoringActivity != null) {
    }
}

private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                    .setContentText("An beacon is nearby.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

public void setMonitoringActivity(MainActivity activity) {
    this.monitoringActivity = activity;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your beacon is not transmitting an AltBeacon packet, which is the only beacon format the code shown is set up to detect.

If your beacon transmitter is sending an Eddystone-UID or iBeacon formatted packet, it is necessary to add a new line with:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        setBeaconLayout("...")
```

Where ... is the proper layout expression for your beacon type.  You can do a Google search to easily find the proper layout string for your beacon type.

Comment: In your reference app that I wrote above, when I use RangingActivity.java class, application detects beacon on **onBeaconServiceConnect()** function. There isn't any problem in this. But while application is running, if I touch home button and app goes to background as you know. And app goes to **Pause** method in RanginActivity.java. I guess beacon scanning must continue in  **BeaconDetection** class. And when any beacon detected, **didEnterRegion()** function must be detected. But  in **RangingActivity.java** class **onBeaconServiceConnect()** function  is triggered again. How can I solve ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I do not understand the problem.  You are saying didEnterRegion() is never called, yes?  If true, this is the real problem to be solved.  It is normal for onBeaconServiceConnect to be called each time the ranging activity is launched.  That is not a problem.

Comment: In the reference app, the Application class uses the RegionBootstrap to connect to the beacon service. Then if and when it finds a beacon, didEnterRegion is called.  I would set a breakpoint on this method or add a debug line, and verify it gets called when the beacon is turned on.  If it is not, verify with the off the shelf Locate Beacon Android app that you can detect the beacon and verify whether it is an iBeacon or other type.